# ¿Como solucionar "el termino 'tsc' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet? en visual studio code - typescript

Tags: nodejs, typescript

para usar TypeScript en Visual Studio Code he seguido los pasos de instalación tanto con el Node.js hasta el TypeScript en consola por cmd, todo me fue bien hasta ese punto, pero a la hora de mostrar en consola en la terminal del archivo ts en visual studio code, me manda el siguiente error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los archivos que he creado son los siguientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya he intentado agregar una nueva variable de entorno del archivo path con la direccion que aparece a la hora de instalar pero aun sigo con el problema, agradecería mucho la ayuda. Quiero que la terminal me muestre el resultado de la instruccion console.log();

Comment: Cierra y vuelve a habría el visual studio

Comment: ¿Has instalado *Typescript* de forma global? `npm install -g typescript`

Comment: Ya lo he intentado de esa forma, estaba buscando y me parece que es algo con la activacion del power shell

Comment: ¿Lo instalaste de forma global o local? Si no utilizaste el argumento `-g` al momento de instalarlo como menciona @VRoxa entonces intenta con: `npx tsc holaMundo`

Comment: ricardo-dlc he probado con el comando npx tsc holaMundo en una maquina virtual y ya me mando el archivo js y también el mensaje en consola, pero en mi maquina fisico no lo ha echo, parece ser que el problema radica en mi laptop o hay alguna configuración que no me permite realizar el trabajo.

Answer (score 1):

## Explicación general

Tienes 2 formas para trabajar con proyectos de typescript, una es instalándolo de forma global, y la otra es instalándolo de forma local únicamente para el proyecto. En términos generales **recomiendo trabajar con la 2da opción (o sea instalándolo localmente en el proyecto)**, por la sencilla razón de que siempre están actualizando typescript: *Si quieres usar una versión más reciente, tendrás que actualizar el paquete que instalaste de forma global periódicamente, lo cual puede generar algún problema si es que tienes algún proyecto que hayas escrito con alguna versión más vieja de typescript.*

## Cómo crear un proyecto con TS

Primero crea una carpeta vacía, y ejecuta en esa carpeta:

```
npm i -y
```

Con eso crearás un archivo package.json con la configuración por defecto. Ahora para instalar typescript y las definiciones de node de forma local:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript @types/node
```

Eso hará que se instale como dependencia local solo para tu proyecto la versión más reciente de typescript, independiente de qué versión salga después, te quedarás con la última versión que se instaló.

## Desarrollar con TS de forma local

Primero crea el archivo `tsconfig.json` con el siguiente comando:

```
npx tsc --init
```

Seguramente te preguntarás por qué colocamos antes `npx`, bueno, la razón es que con ese prefijo le decimos a `npm` que **ejecute el cli de typescript que está instalado localmente** en el proyecto.

La forma en cómo normalmente se trabaja typescript es definiendo una carpeta de desarrollo (comúnmente llamada `src`), y otra con los archivos transpilados (comúnmente llamada `dist`). Por lo cual, para una configuración mínima compatible con ello recomiendo dejar el `tsconfig.json` de esta forma:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "rootDir": "./src/",

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
  }
}
```

Opcionalmente, si lo vas a subir a algún repositorio remoto con git, entonces recomiendo hacer un archivo `.gitignore` excluyendo las carpetas de transpilación y la de dependencias:

```
# Excluir estas carpetas
node_modules
dist
```

Entonces tu proyecto debería tener una estructura como esta:

```
proyect
├── dist
├── node_modules
├── src
│   └── index.ts
├── .gitignore
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Todo lo que escribas en `.ts` debe quedar dentro de `src`, entonces para compilar bastará con escribir en la terminal:

```
npx tsc
```

...o en caso de que quieras que compile automáticamente ante cualquier cambio:

```
npx tsc -w
```

## Implementar proyecto

Cuando tengas todo listo y necesites implementar en producción, normalmente lo **clonarás desde tu repositorio remoto.** Y gracias al archivo `.gitignore`, lo único que tendrás será:

```
proyect
├── src
│   └── index.ts
├── .gitignore
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Entonces desde la terminal instalaremos todas las dependencias:

```
npm install
```

Luego transpilamos el proyecto:

```
npx tsc
```

Y finalmente lo ejecutamos directamente:

```
node ./dist/index.js
```